# Is it acceptable to post an answer to a question that has been answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753849/simple-progress-bar-for-image-upload-immediately-at-100) question has been answered in the comments of the question, would it be acceptable for me to use the link that the person has posted to post an answer?